# Is an employer required to notify changes to approved time off?

Tags: employment

I have an agreement with my children’s father to meet up at the end of the school year and at the beginning of the school year for him to have them for the summer time. So I place at least six months to a year in advance the time needed to be able to travel as we meet in another state for this parental agreement.
The time off for the first request to meet is in my file to “take my girls to see their father”, however the second request that was approved to “pick my children up” has been removed from my file as well as days on schedule for time off has been removed.

I understand employers can revoke at anytime, however does the employer have to notify you that they have revoked previously approved time off?
Why would they dispose of my paper work to make it look like “what paper work"?
They don’t pay OT.. they frustrate me so

Comment: Can you give us some sort of hint to what legal jurisdiction may be at play.

Comment: Where in the world are you? If in the US, which state? Do you have a contract specifying details, or are you on a verbal agreement or default contract that doesn't specify anything besides the legal default for your juristiction?

Comment: Have you asked them why the file is missing?  Do you have copies of any of these files?  If not, you should immediately make some.

Comment: Jurisdiction is important here. In Germany, for example, employers can only revoke already confirmed vacation requests with a good reason, and they then have to reimburse the employee all cost related (e.g. booked flights and accommodation that cannot be cancelled anymore)

Answer (score 2):

Management certainly need to notify you that a previously approved time off request has been denied; otherwise you don't know that they expect you to be at work.

How much advance notice is required varies by country and by company policy.

Note that if you didn't get acknowledgement that you were being allowed the time off, you may have to assume it was not approved. If you do get acknowledgement, always save a copy, just as you would save a receipt, so if someone or something forgets you have evidence you can present. And keep your manager in the loop -- remind them several weeks in advance of when you'll be out, and monitor your department calendar so you can discuss any conflicts that are arising. That increases the odds of your finding and fixing any confusion before it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poorly written and difficult to understand and follow so you may want to clean it up a bit. Also, please add your location such as country and state if within the US.

Also, the facts of exchanging children with your ex are completely irrelevant. This is simply a question of "I requested time off for 6 months into the future, they approved it and now denied it". The personal details are irrelevant whether you are traveling out of state for a custody arrangement or staying home to paint the house... they make no difference.

With that being said, most employers have the right to revoke approved time off but you would need to look at the company policies. Do you have an employee handbook, for example?

Have you had a chat with your boss and explained that he/she has previously approved your time off request and that you have already made arrangements based on that decision? Or simply ask why it was revoked? Sometimes a simply face to face chat can clear up.

Lastly, you have a few other options. The obvious one is to find a new job. You've got 6 months notice of the potential problem so find something else and then have them write the time off request into your offer letter. You can also let them know that you will not be here on such-and-such of a date. You're not asking but letting them know. Then when the time comes, remind your boss and take the time off then let them handle it as they see fit while being prepared to be fired over it.

When I was an engineering manager I always told my direct reports that they never had to ask me to take time off but to inform me given the caveat that the time off did not impact anything that they specifically were working on.

Comment: I'd say taking your children so they can be with their father is not trivial in the slightest. And I think the father would agree. The OP is explaining to their boss why they need time off, it would take seconds for her employer to verify that she is a single mother, divorced or separated. It would take maybe some minutes to confirm whether the father is living in a different state or not. The request is not unreasonable and the trip, presumably, cannot be postponed one  or two weeks later whereas painting the house can be delayed or can be done by other people.

Comment: I also find the initial observation *Your question is very poorly written and difficult to understand* to be unnecessarily rude, and untrue. I looked at the original version, it was not difficult to understand at all. Two typos/misspellings but the rest is perfectly understandable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I never once said that her issue was trivial so please reread my post before the hyperbole starts. Of course it is an important issue to her life, the kids' lives and the father's life but none of it is really relevant. She had approved time off and now they are backtracking. A conversation could fix it. You're also entitled to your opinion but the original question was indeed VERY poorly written. Facts over feelings.

Answer (score -9):

I'm presuming you are in the US, this is borderline VTC because it's due to Workplace policy/local Law.

However...

My *personal* view is that in most cases anything more than 3 months worth of notice isn't a request. It's a notification.

You aren't *asking* for the time off, you are informing the company you aren't going to be at work for those time(s) and they need to make alternate arrangements.

Do you have any form of proof that you requested the days off at the same time? If so, point to that inform them that you aren't going to be at work.

Comment: Your personal view is irrelevant and has no bearing on what employers can or cannot actually legally do. This is of no help to the OP. It is likely that in the US the employer can say “too bad, leave request cancelled, if you don’t show up you’re fired”.

Comment: @nobody - If the OP is correct and they asked 6 months to a year in advance - that falls IMO well inside the 'Notification' scenario - that is, you aren't asking, you are informing. I understand the US has some rather interesting ideas around taking leave etc. but even then - after a period of time, it's not a request.

Comment: That might be your personal view but that's not how it generally works, a request for leave is just that - *request*. It's up to your manager to approve or reject it, you're not automatically owed the exact days you want regardless of what you might think. Making your requests early in advance generally increases the likelihood of them being approved but that's about it.

Comment: @AnnaAG That depends on jurisdiction. In The Netherlands, employers are legally required to grant leave requests if they are placed at least two weeks in advance. They have those two weeks to object if they have objections for "zwaarwegende bedrijfsbelangen" (weighty business interests), for example your alternate is also on vacation, and there is no one else to do your job, and not doing that for the period of your leave would result in severe damage to the business. An employee is also legally required to take two weeks of consecutive leave each year, and the employer must ensure you do.

Comment: @AnnaAG Also, if they object, they have to allow you to take leave another time (e.g. not continuously object, for example if you're the only employee that can do something, that is the problem of the employer).